# PHP:How to echo description from HTML Input tag after doing array

Tags: php, html

Firstly sorry if the title make some of you confuse ... here's the real problem.

I am developing a system that generates a receipt from HTML Form. The real problem is that I don't know how to get all descriptions because I'm using multiple input controls on the form.

In `add.php`, there are some description boxes where staff can enter the purchased info. I'm using Input. The code's are:

```
<input type='text' name='desc[1]' size='40px'><!-- (I'll copy paste it 9 times) -->
```

This is the only place to enter all info, then it will redirect to view the order info.

I can echo everything using `$_REQUEST`, but I don't know how to echo this. People say it's an array but I don't understand it that much.

Here some code:

Add.php

```
<?php

include 'server.php';
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $order = $_POST['order'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $orderdate = $_POST['orderdate'];
    $firstfit = $_POST['firstfit'];
    $event = $_POST['event'];
    $desc = $_POST['desc'];
    $color = $_POST['color'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];

    $syntax = "INSERT INTO `client` (`order`,`name`,`tel`,`orderdate`,`firstfit`,`event`,`desc`,`color`) VALUES ('$order','$name','$tel','$orderdate','$firstfit','$event','$desc','$color')";
    $insert = mysqli_query($config, $syntax);
    header("Location: do.php");
}
```

Then here's the input

```
<tr>
    <th>DESCRIPTION :</th>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="desc[1]" size="90px"><br>
        <input type="text" name="desc[2]" size="90px"><br>
        <input type="text" name="desc[3]" size="90px"><br>
        <input type="text" name="desc[4]" size="90px"><br>
        <input type="text" name="desc[5]" size="90px"><br>
        <input type="text" name="desc[6]" size="90px"><br>
        <input type="text" name="desc[7]" size="90px"><br>
        <input type="text" name="desc[8]" size="90px"><br>
        <input type="text" name="desc[9]" size="90px"><br>
    </td>
</tr>
```

So how can I echo out all the 9 different descriptions into the receipt? 
I'm sorry if this question is not clear because I'm still a beginner :-(

Comment: You should consult a tutorial. Your script is wide open to SQL injections. The query needs to be parameterized. Your `$desc` is an array and needs to be iterated over. `$syntax` is a bad name for a variable. Once you get to outputting look at XSS injections, you'll need to prevent those as well. It seems like you are a bit away from outputting though.

Comment: I'll just start a new semester (Introduction to Web Development). Everything new to me and this is my side project. Thank's for your advised. Really appreciate it